# sed - match regex in specific position

Tags: regex, sed, substring

I'm having some trouble creating a one liner or a simple script to edit some fixed length files using sed.

Supposing my file has lines in this format:

IPITTYTHEFOOBUTIDONOTPITTYTHEBAR

IPITTYTH BARBUTIDONOTPITTYTH3FOO

If the entire lines are considered as a string, I can say I would want to match the substring that starts in position 10 and has length 3 with a regex. If it matches the regex I want to had some other string in the end of that line.

Assuming the matching regex is `B.R`, and the string to append in the end of the line is `NOT`, I would want my file to turn into:

IPITTYTHE**FOO**BUTIDONOTPITTYTHEBAR

IPITTYTH **BAR**BUTIDONOTPITTYTHEFOONOT

The lines in the files are bigger than the ones in this sample.

So far I have this:

```
sed -i '/B.R/ s/$/NOT/' file.name
```

The problem is that this ignores the position where the regex is matched, making the first line of the example a match as well:

IPITTYTHEFOOBUTIDONOTPITTYTHE**BAR**

IPITTYTH **BAR**BUTIDONOTPITTYTH3FOO

I'm open to use awk as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to specify the characters which exists before `B.R` . If `B` is at 10th position then there must be 9 characters exists before `B`

```
sed -i '/^.\{9\}B.R/s/$/NOT/' file.name
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed  '/^.\{9\}B.R/s/$/NOT/' file
IPITTYTHEFOOBUTIDONOTPITTYTHEBAR
IPITTYTH BARBUTIDONOTPITTYTHEFOONOT
```